# django : SetPasswordForm is not valid without error

Tags: python, django, forms, web, passwords

This is my first time to use SetPasswordForm. The form is not valid but does not shows error message. So I'm having hard time to figure out which part went wrong.

urls.py

```
url(r'^password_change/(?P<username>[-\w.]+)/$', views.password_change, name='password_change'),
url(r'^password_change_done/$', views.password_change_done, name='password_change_done'),
```

When user input their new password and if the action succeeded, the page will redirect to password_change_done.

views.py

```
@login_required
def password_change(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():            
            oldpassword = form.cleaned_data.get('oldpassword')
            password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            password2 = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
            if password1 == password2:
                update_session_auth_hash(request, form.username)
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/password_change_done/') 
            else:
                return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', {'error_message': 'password mismatch'})
        else:
        return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', {'error_messages': form.errors })
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('blog:profile', args=[form.user.get_username()]))


@login_required
def password_change_done(request):
return render(request, 'blog/password_change_done.html')
```

forms.py

```
class PasswordChangeForm(SetPasswordForm):
    error_messages = dict(SetPasswordForm.error_messages, **{
    'password_incorrect': ("Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again."),
    })
    oldpassword = forms.CharField(
        label=("Old password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}),
    )
    field_order = ['oldpassword', 'password1', 'password2']
    def __init__(self, user, data, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(PasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(data, **kwargs)
    def clean_oldpassword(self):
        oldpassword = self.cleaned_data["oldpassword"]
        if not self.user.check_password(oldpassword):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_incorrect'],
                code='password_incorrect',
            )
        return oldpassword
```

templates.py

```
{{ form.errors }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% if error_message %}
    <h2><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></h2>
{% else %}<br>
{% endif %}
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'blog:password_change' user.username %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="button-primary">submit</button></div>
</form>
```

I put {{ form.errors }} and {{ form.non_field_errors }} so if error happens than it can display error message on website. However till now no message displayed and seems like nothing happens whenever user click submit button.

Comment: How are you determining that the form is not valid? Also note you should be doing the password comparison inside the form's `clean` method, that way you can return a form error rather than a separate variable.

Comment: can you try print(form.is_valid()) inside your view after form is created?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I put print under form is vaild() and else, and only print where I put in the else part showing in the console, and password was thae smae, so I guessed that form is not valid

Comment: @DanielRoseman I couldn't understand that I should be doing the password comaprison inside of form's clean method. Doing comparison after clean method does not work?

Comment: Well, the errors won't show because you don't pass either the form or a variable called "error_message" to the template, you only pass "error_messages" with an s. Really, you should just return the form.

Comment: And the whole point of a form is that you do this comparison there, rather than in the view.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov yes, I tried print inside of view and the print does not dispalyed in the console regardless how I change my code. only the print I put under else: part displayed in the console.

Comment: @camila so you click on the button in the form and then only print() in else statement is shown? That cannot happen, you have post method defined in form. can you print(request.method)?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I put print(request.method) under the else: part, and it in console it displayed POST, but still form is not vaild

Comment: @camila if form is not valid - debug it further with print(form.errors)

Answer (score 2):

You have quite a few issues here, but the main problem - as I have told you before - is how you are passing things to the template. You need to follow the pattern as shown in the documentation, and you need to be *consistent* about your variable naming.

Firstly, move your password check to the form itself:

```
class PasswordChangeForm(SetPasswordForm):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 1= password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('password mismatch')
```

Now, fix your view:

```
def password_change(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.username)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/password_change_done/') 
        else:
            return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', {'form': form })
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('blog:profile', args=[username]))
```

And finally, remove `{{ error_messages }}` from your template.

Comment: When I use cleaned_data, it should form not self??